# Navigating inside a webpage without appending #href (browser back button)

Tags: javascript, html

How to navigate to sections inside a webpage without remembering history? That is, suppose I use the following code. When I click on `About`, it takes me to the About section. But it also adds #about in the URL. The problem is, if I click 10 times alternating between `Home` and `About` to navigate inside the page, then when I click the browser back button I backtracks all my actions like a stack. I want it to completely come out of the webpage. How to achieve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#home"> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about"> About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <section id="home" style="margin-top: 100%">
        Home Sweet Home!
    </section>
    <section id="about" style="margin-top: 100%">
        About Me
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: If it is not possible with only html, using java Script is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the job with pure HTML like this:

```html
<body>
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#home" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('about').style.display='none';document.getElementById('home').style.display='block';history.pushState(null,null,'home')"> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('home').style.display='none';document.getElementById('about').style.display='block';history.pushState(null,null,'about')"> About</a></li>
</ul>
<section id="home" style="">
    Home Sweet Home!
</section>
<section id="about" style="display: none;">
    About Me
</section>
</body>
```

It's just so you get the idea, but in practice, you should write more organized JavaScript and probably need help from a library like JQuery to build a useful website or app with navigation. Even in this example, there's a lot of room for improvement:

- There's a lot of long and repetitive code crammed in it, a problem an external JavaScript script or app will solve.
- Thanks to `history.pushState`, the button link and browser back/forth works as expected (look in the address bar to see the URL change without refreshing page), but as soon as you refresh page, you'll get an error. You need a web server to serve the right content for this to work, with help from the client too.

#### Update

Improved version with organized script and animation to demonstrate what you can do with in-file CSS and script.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <title>testing</title>
   <style>
        section {
            position: absolute;
            left: -800px;
            top: 100px;
            transition: left .6s;
        }
        section.visible {
            left: 200px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function navTo(page) {
            if (page === 'about') {
                document.getElementById('home').classList.remove('visible');
                document.getElementById('about').classList.add('visible');
                history.pushState(null, null, 'about');
            } else {
                document.getElementById('about').classList.remove('visible');
                document.getElementById('home').classList.add('visible');
                history.pushState(null, null, 'home');
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#home" onclick="event.preventDefault();navTo('home')">
        Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" onclick="event.preventDefault();navTo('about')">
        About</a></li>
</ul>
<section id="home" class="visible">
    Home Sweet Home!
</section>
<section id="about">
    About Me
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `;history.pushState(null,null,'about')` do? Everything seems to work fine without it.

Comment: @SeverusTux That's part of History API that allows you to nav back/forward. Added some demonstrating animation

Comment: If I comment out both the `history.pushState...`, I don't see any difference.

Comment: There's a difference though not readily visible. You can make it work without history., but you can't use the back button to move back / forth (home -> about -> back to home etc.), you're only on one single page. That's an important part of your question I suppose

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
element.scrollIntoView()
```

```
element=document.getElementById("element's id")
```

in html:

```
<a onclick="elementId.scrollIntoView()">element name</a>
```

note: any tag will do...  the `<a>` will lose the underscore and color change - could be fixed with style.  how about (flat, with style) buttons?